# Different loading content without reloading page than interval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to update - Load more content from database without using Set Interval to refresh automatic after sec or more...

Comment: If you have any code for this share with us ? Also the reason to not use setIntarval ?

Comment: I cant send my get values to file that need to be refreshed But i need those values inside that file as well so the other things would work...

Comment: If you want to refresh automatically you will have to use intervals, you can use it to check for changes and then update if any. That way you won't update the data to an equal one.

Comment: So can I use ajax to send GET values to my page I want to set interval on?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes can I send some values trough ajax onload function?

Answer (score 0):

For getting data from you server without refreshing the page you have to use `AJAX`.

You can read more about `ajax` using `jquery` here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

If you want to make a request to server every 5 seconds you can use `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

If you still have problems please include what have you tried (code).

Comment: @Noob and what is your problem? What is not working ok?

Comment: I asked is there other way? I have file where I have GET vals for sender and reciver. I need to send those vals to file that is refreshing. Because when I include that file it works but when I load it with interval it cant get those vals...